# Append column to query result

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following Access 2007 table:

```
Company | Item | Quantity
-------------------------
AA      | Ia   | 2
BB      | Ib   | 3
CC      | Ia   | 4
AA      | Ib   | 5
```

and I'd like to create a query with the following result

```
Company | Ia  | Ib
------------------ 
AA      | 2   | 5
BB      |     | 3
CC      | 4   |
```

But I am really kind of lost right now.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Do you have a fixed set of possible items, or does it have to be dynamic?  I.e., will it always be `Ia` and `Ib` with two columns in the output?

Comment: @njk This is an MS Access question, SQL is a generic tag. MS Access is a RAD tool, so a knowledge of SQL is additional to the use of MS Access, not central.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a typical crosstab query:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(XTabTable.Quantity) AS SumOfQuantity
SELECT XTabTable.Company
FROM XTabTable
GROUP BY XTabTable.Company
PIVOT XTabTable.Item;
```

It can be built using Access query wizards or the query design window.

[image: xtab query]

Answer (score 2):

Another method that you can build your own pivot/cross tab. It's fully ANSI Compliant. So for the sample I used `SQL Server` as it's more inlined with MS ACCESS SQL. Please ignore the other tables in the fiddle...

### * [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0bd13/11)

Query:

```
Select
 company,
 'Ia'=Sum(Case When item = 'Ia' Then Quantity Else 0 End),
 'Ib'=Sum(Case When item = 'Ib' Then Quantity Else 0 End)
 From mytable
 Group By company
 ;
```

**Edit:** MS Access doesn't support `CASE`. So we will *shortcircuit* it with `IIF`.

```
 Select
 company,
 Sum(IIF(item = 'Ia', Quantity, 0)) AS Ia,
 Sum(IIF(item = 'Ia', Quantity, 0)) AS Ib
 From mytable
 Group By company
 ;
```

Results:

```
    COMPANY     IA  IB
    AA          2   5
    BB          0   3
    CC          4   0
```

Orcourse this is only convenient when you have a smalle number of `items`. Since you are using MS Acess you might as well use its built in functionalities :) like how @Remou pointed out.

Comment: @user589117 please give a try on this when you are interested in :) Sorry I had put the wrong reference. Just updated.

Comment: MS Access does not support CASE, I am afraid.

Comment: @Remou then let's `shortcircuit` ;)

Comment: @Remou Bingo I found [MSDN](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/iif-function-HA001228853.aspx) and one of [yourposts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882099/summing-only-if-a-certain-customer-in-ms-access-2003) ;)

Comment: @ bonCodigo: Finally this has helped me quite a bit, thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

If you ever decide to store you data in a SQL Server database here is a way you could do it:

```
Declare @columns Nvarchar(Max), @SQL Nvarchar(Max)

With    DistinctCols As
(
        Select  Distinct Item
        From    AccessTable
)
Select  @columns = Coalesce(@columns + ',','') + '[' + Item + ']'
From    DistinctCols
Order   By Item

Select  @SQL = 'Select  Company, ' + @columns + '
                From    AccessTable at
                Pivot   (Sum(Quantity) For Item In (' + @columns + ')) p'

Exec    sp_executeSQL @SQL
```

Comment: Why do you think an SQL Server answer is suitable for an MS Access question? Do you add MS Access answers to SQL Server questions?

Comment: Since the title is kind of generic "Append column to query result" and this came up when I did a search of SQL tags I figured someone could potentially get to this page looking for a similar answer except for a SQL table. That was my logic in adding a response. I'm fairly new though and obviously you aren't so if this is not a useful methodology I won't do that anymore.

Comment: I think you will find that a lot of the titles are quite generic because SO discourages tags in headings, so you are not supposed to day, for example  "Append column to query result in MS Access" because MS Access appears in the tags. This means you need to check both the title and the tags to get where the question is coming from. Good luck, have fun.